# SyntaxError invalid syntax python

Tags: python

```py
def convert():
    choice = input("Wybierz kierunek wymiany waluty \n1) PLN>USD \n2) USD>PLN \n3) PLN>EURO \n4) EURO>PLN")
    print(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        print ("choice=1")

    else choice == 2:
        print("Choice=2")

    else choice == 3:
        print("Choice=3")

    else choice == 4:
        print("Choice=4")

convert()
```

Why is there a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`?

Comment: `else choice == 2:` did you mean `elif choice == 2:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this trio in python: `if`, `elif`, and `else`. There can only be one `else`, because, just think of what it actually means: only do something when all other conditions don't pass.

```
def convert():
    choice = input("Wybierz kierunek wymiany waluty \n1) PLN>USD \n2) USD>PLN \n3) PLN>EURO \n4) EURO>PLN")
    print(choice)

    if choice == 1:
        print ("choice=1")

    elif choice == 2:
        print("Choice=2")

    elif choice == 3:
        print("Choice=3")

    elif choice == 4:
        print("Choice=4")

convert()
```

Comment: if choice == "1": userusd1 = input("Enter the buying price: ") userpln = input("Enter the amount in PLN: ") wynik = userusd1 * userpln print(wynik) How to multiply userusd * userpln

Comment: Use float(): userusd1 = float(input("Enter the buying price: "))

Comment: Thank you why when I write 3,80 USD i see ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,8' ? But I write 3.8 is good.

Comment: because python only allows dots as decimal points, unless you have a special module.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to continue the program if I don't provide any value? Of course, if I do not type anything and click, type pops up ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: You can use an error handler: try: userusd1 = float(input("Enter the buying price: ")) except: print('Invalid')

Comment: Not working gets an answer a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You need at least two lines.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant `elif`- there is no `else <cond>` in python:

```py
def convert():
    choice = input("Wybierz kierunek wymiany waluty \n1) PLN>USD \n2) USD>PLN \n3) PLN>EURO \n4) EURO>PLN")
    print(choice)
    if choice == "1":
        print("choice=1")
    elif choice == "2":
        print("Choice=2")
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Choice=3")
    elif choice == "4":
        print("Choice=4")

convert()
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) for how to use if-elif-else.

Answer (score 0):

While traditional way to fix your code is by replacing all `else` except the last one with `elif` as follows:

```
def convert():
    choice = input("Wybierz kierunek wymiany waluty \n1) PLN>USD \n2) USD>PLN \n3) PLN>EURO \n4) EURO>PLN")
    print(choice)
    if choice == "1":
        print("choice=1")
    elif choice == "2":
        print("Choice=2")
    elif choice == "3":
        print("Choice=3")
    elif choice == "4":
        print("Choice=4")

convert()
```

However for your particular case, even if else isn't needed. You can go for:

```
def convert():
        choice = input("Wybierz kierunek wymiany waluty \n1) PLN>USD \n2) USD>PLN \n3) PLN>EURO \n4) EURO>PLN")
        print(choice)
        print("choice=", choice)

convert()
```